# Android Asset Delivery in Xamarin

Tags: android, xamarin

I have a Xamarin Project with a lot of assets (images) in the Resources\Images directory that shall be deployed to the Google Play Store. This means that the size of the generated aab package is way beyond the Google Play Store limit of 150MB. (Message: Your App Bundle contains the following configurations where the initial install would exceed the maximum size of 150 MB...)

My current solution resizes the images to <= 150MB. now I saw that there a possibility to generate separate files for the assets called Play Feature Delivery.

From this sample project I get the following gradle file to create an install-time-package:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.asset-pack'

assetPack {
    packName = "install_time_asset_pack" // Directory name for the asset pack
    dynamicDelivery {
        deliveryType = "install-time" // delivery mode
    }
}
```

My question is: Can this somehow be done with Xamarin? Is it possible to add some elements to the csproj-file to do this, just like for example for the keystore.

Comment: There is an open discussion around the work that would be needed to support Dynamic Feature modules, like Asset Bundles, on the Xam.Android github repository. See: [Support for Dynamic Feature Modules ] (https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-android/issues/4810) .     You can also check [Xamarin.Android Asset Delivery](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/xamarinandroid-asset-delivery/1527043) .

Comment: Have you been able to use Android Asset Delivery for Xamarin.Android? Were you able to solve this problem?